# How to enable log4j appender in EJB JAR used on web project?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, log4j

I have a web project with an EJB jar in its `WEB-INF/lib`. The EJB uses log4j, and have it's own properties file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=C:/Documents and Settings/u10981/Escritorio/log_C1.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=3072KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p][%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] - %m%n

log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p][%C][%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] - %m%n
```

When I deploy the web project on JBoss, the programs runs fine, but the log is not written. But in Eclipse's console the logs appear as normal. I think the appender is not working well. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are aware that you leave the servlet specification and go into vendor specific territory when using the filesystem directly?  Consider instead to use slf4j and log to the jdk14 backend allowing the server to collect the logs.

Comment: I cannot change that specific. The logger must be from the application itself, and its location must be external to the server path.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I gave up to your advice, Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen. (or so I think)

I used info from another post to create an appender in the standalone.xml of JBoss and a handler to save it, just that the path is absolute, and yes, against any good practice must be that way.

> ```
>         <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILETWO">
>             <formatter>
>                 <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
>             </formatter>
>             <file path="C:/Documents and Settings/u10981/Escritorio/log_C1.log"/>
>             <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
>             <append value="true"/>
>         </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
> ```

```
        <logger category="pe.com.projectavalon.Prueba">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
                <handler name="FILETWO"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```

The log is saving as I hoped. So everything solved. Thanks for your help =)